# Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) in UWP app

Tags: uwp, file-access, folder-access

[GitHub Link for the project](https://github.com/sharathcng/Folder-File-Access-In-UWP.git)

```
private async void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify the folder path
    string folderPath = @"C:\\RGNEW";
    
    // Get the StorageFolder from the path
    StorageFolder folder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath).AsTask().Result;
    
    // Add the folder to FutureAccessList with the folder path as the token
    string token = folderPath; // You can customize the token if needed
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(token, folder);
}
```

Encountering **Access is denied**. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) error
in UWP app when attempting **direct folder creation and file read/write on the C:\ drive**.

The project has the **broadFileSystemAccess **capability, and I have **enabled file access** in both the file system settings for the app and through **right-clicking on the app and selecting app settings**.

Despite these configurations, the issue persists. Seeking guidance on resolving permissions issues and exploring alternatives to enable direct folder creation without relying on user selection. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I downloaded your project and test on my side. I didn't get Access exception.  Using `@"C:\\RGNEW"` gives me **Value does not fall within the expected range** error. After changing the path to `@"C:\RGNEW"`. The `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` works correctly.

Comment: Have you checked the file path to see if this is the issue?

Comment: Yep, it's up and running! But you know what would be slick? Creating that folder on the fly when a user logs in, right in the C directory. No need for manual folder gymnastics – just a quick check and boom, folder's there!I'm thinking about creating a slick folder in the C:\ directory. If it's not there, no worries, the app should just create it and download some cool files. But, if it's already hanging out, it should snoop around, count the files, and let me know so I can fetch the rest from the API. Thoughts?